# S3 Object Lambda WriteGetObjectResponse API returns 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-js

The code is running on AWS Lambda Node.js 14 runtime using the AWS SDK for JavaScript version 2.868.0.

Here is the code snippet:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const objectContent = event['getObjectContext'];
    const data = await s3.writeGetObjectResponse({
        Body: 'test',
        RequestRoute: objectContent['outputRoute'],
        RequestToken: objectContent['outputToken']
    }).promise();
    console.log(data);
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200
    };
    return response;
};
```

I have attached the following IAM policy to the Lambda role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowObjectLambdaAccess",
            "Action": [
                "s3-object-lambda:WriteGetObjectResponse"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The function throws the following error on the line `await s3.writeGetObjectResponse(...).promise()`:

```
2021-03-22T01:59:29.951Z    eb99f9a6-75c7-40ec-9f85-e19da084c42c    ERROR   Invoke Error    {
    "errorType": "MethodNotAllowed",
    "errorMessage": "The specified method is not allowed against this resource.",
    "code": "MethodNotAllowed",
    "message": "The specified method is not allowed against this resource.",
    "region": null,
    "time": "2021-03-22T01:59:29.891Z",
    "requestId": "C0FKZ5WSK027GPQW",
    "extendedRequestId": "+9rRhWJUPgIAmFupxXKrkAIWe5dXbi0vAacoN+/NlCQPgKzyZi0+mpevGMIVDDPo/1EYpo8Ntyk=",
    "statusCode": 405,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 15.885104429810148,
    "stack": [
        "MethodNotAllowed: The specified method is not allowed against this resource.",
        "    at Request.extractError (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:712:35)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
        "    at Request.emit (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
        "    at Request.emit (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)",
        "    at Request.transition (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "    at /opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Update: the issue was fixed in [2.876.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/.changes/2.876.0.json). Please update to the latest version to avoid any need for the workaround.

---

I heard that the SDK team is working on the fix. The issue is related to the endpoint. You can actually see which endpoint is used if you `console.log` the result of `s3.WriteGetObjectResponse(...)`.

For now you can use this workaround:

```
//Construct the client with an endpoint override so the request lands in the right place
const client = new AWS.S3({ region: "us-east-1", endpoint: "s3-object-lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"});

// Override the signing service name from s3 to s3-object-lambda so the signatures are valid.
client.__proto__.api.endpointPrefix = "s3-object-lambda";
const data = await client.writeGetObjectResponse({
    Body: 'test',
    RequestRoute: objectContent['outputRoute'],
    RequestToken: objectContent['outputToken']
}).promise();
```

I run into exact same issue while experimenting with the feature and the workaround worked well for me.

In case it turns out to be useful I combined an article based on the learnings, can be used as [a small tutorial to S3 Object Lambda](https://olena-k.medium.com/how-to-use-amazon-s3-object-lambda-to-generate-thumbnails-e16ae36a33ea).

Comment: Hi, do you know the equivalent of this for typescript? I can't use `__proto__` in my typescript code.

Comment: Petra, the issue was already fixed (in version 2.876.0 - https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/.changes/2.876.0.json). With the new version you won't need the workaround :)

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot @anelook!

Answer (score 0):

I have opened a bug issue on AWS SDK Github https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3675 as it seems to be an SDK problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to temporary fix this issue until the bug is not solved

```
/** START Workaround for bug #3675 **/
const s3 = new AWS.S3({ region: "us-east-1", endpoint: "s3-object-lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" });
s3.__proto__.api.endpointPrefix = "s3-object-lambda";
/** END Workaround for bug #3675 **/
```

I've documented the usage in my [medium blog](https://micheleriso.medium.com/serverless-framework-use-aws-s3-object-lambda-to-resize-images-on-the-fly-868a37017f3c) if that can help