# MethodNotAllowed: The specified method is not allowed against this resource error in nodejs Aws S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I just create one lambda function and configure this lambda function with S3 Object Lambda Access Points. When i call this lambda function with S3 Object Lambda Access Points Then It's return following Error.

**ERROR:**

```
{
    "errorType": "MethodNotAllowed",
    "errorMessage": "The specified method is not allowed against this resource.",
    "code": "MethodNotAllowed",
    "message": "The specified method is not allowed against this resource.",
    "region": null,
    "time": "2021-03-25T06:53:27.593Z",
    "requestId": "2PSZNM1V2A5H5YA5",
    "extendedRequestId": "cWn4JmcBTbRyrl+IqCakNYeu4Zeca9/l+jdUwlWgVZRZ8H5NPnCCixK3gweUe1logjU9QpSYgK4=",
    "statusCode": 405,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 27.356515607009,
    "stack": [
        "MethodNotAllowed: The specified method is not allowed against this resource.",
        "    at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:712:35)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)",
        "    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"
    ]
}
```

I tried to convert this s3 python example in nodejs. Read More ===> [Introducing Amazon S3 Object Lambda – Use Your Code to Process Data as It Is Being Retrieved from S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-s3-object-lambda-use-your-code-to-process-data-as-it-is-being-retrieved-from-s3/)

**Lambda Function:**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const object_get_context = event["getObjectContext"];
    const request_route = object_get_context["outputRoute"];
    const request_token = object_get_context["outputToken"];
   
    var params = {
        RequestRoute: request_route, 
        RequestToken: request_token, 
        Body: 'TEST TEXT',
    };
    const data = await s3.writeGetObjectResponse(params).promise();
    
    console.log('before return data --->', data);
    return {'status_code': 200};
}
```

**Call Object Lambda Access Points With This Code:**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

var getParams = {
    Bucket: 'arn:aws:s3-object-lambda:xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // Object Lambda Access Points ARN,
    Key: 'test.txt' // path to the object you're looking for
}

s3.getObject(getParams, function(err, data) {
    // Handle any error and exit
    if (err){
        console.log('err ====>', err);
        return err;
    }

  let objectData = data.Body.toString('utf-8'); // Use the encoding necessary
  console.log('objectData ===>', objectData);
});
```

Comment: Looks like the same issue as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66767589/s3-object-lambda-writegetobjectresponse-api-returns-405-method-not-allowed/66800385#66800385).